# Obtaining the sum of correct message byte lengths on the network layer by the Omnet++ result collection

Tags: omnet++

Suppose in a wireless network with 25 nodes, we have a scenario where some of each node sends messages to some other nodes according to a routing protocol such as AODV. We simulate this network. After finishing the simulation, how to obtain the sum of messages byte length on the network layer by the Omnet++ result collection?
For each node, we must have two metrics, a metric for sent message byte lengths (e.g. totalSentMessageByteLengths) and a metric for received message byte lengths (e.g. totalReceivedMessageByteLengths).
By correct messages, I mean messages received by a node whose destination address field is the address of the same node. If retransmission occurs, it should be summed once for the receiver side, summed the incorrect message byte lengths, and the correct message byte lengths for the sender side. If a node has more than an application, all the message byte lengths generated by all applications of the same node must be calculated. Message byte lengths mean the total byte of header and data on the network layer per byte.
An instace code for a node in omnetpp.ini:

```
*.hostA.numApps = 2
*.hostA.app[0].typename = "UdpBasicApp"
*.hostA.app[0].destAddresses = "hostB"
*.hostA.app[0].destPort = 5000
*.hostA.app[0].messageLength = 1000B
*.hostA.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
*.hostA.app[0].packetName = "UDPData"

*.hostA.app[0].typename = "TcpBasicApp"
*.hostA.app[0].destAddresses = "hostC"
*.hostA.app[0].destPort = 5001
*.hostA.app[0].messageLength = 1024B
*.hostA.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(45ms)
*.hostA.app[0].packetName = "TCPData"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ipv4 module has several signals that can be used to create statistics either on a node or network level like `packetSentToLower` or `packetReceivedFromLower`. Just use these signals on your @statistics declaration.

Comment: Mr. Rudi, have you an example for mentioned signals?